# Можете объяснить как работает данный код

Tags: javascript, бинарное-дерево

пишу функцию для обратного обхода дерева поиска с приоритетом направо RLN , реализации на с++ не нашел толком , только на javascript . Сам алгоритм обхода понятен , но как он происходит в этой функции - не совсем , можете объяснить поподробнее ?

```
function traversal(tree) {
    // если это не лист
    if ( tree.refs ) {
        // последовательно справа налево обходим ветви, ведущие к потомкам
        for (let i = tree.refs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            traversal( tree.refs[i] ); // рекурсия
        }
    }
    // ...обработка данных узла...
    console.log(tree.data); // просто выводим в консоль
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Странно это читать: "*пишу функцию ... реализации на с++ не нашел толком*" — ведь если *пишу*, то для чего *искать* чужую реализацию?...

Comment: если у нас дерево представлено вв иде графа(списки смежности, матрица смежности, то из каждой вершины у нас будет два потомка(индексы вершин, от них мы и запускаем рекурсивный обход дерева)) иначе, дерево это структура с указателями на левый и правый потомки, мы спускаемся по дереву так: запускаем рекурсия сначала от правого потомка потом обрабатываем данную вершину потом запускаем рекурсию от левого сына это даст обход справа на лево, для обратного обхода надо поменять местами запуски рекурсии

Answer (score 0):

for (let i = tree.refs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) - цикл

tree.refs.length - длинна передаваемой переменной

tree.refs.length - берем и отнимаем от длинны 1 каждый раз когда запускается цикл

Мы берем и отнимаем от этого значения один и цикл работает пока оно не станет 0

console.log(tree.data); - вывод значения

Я могу и ошибатся, я учу пайтон, а не С++, но мы его в институте изучаем и могу немного его расшифровать

Comment: А в вопросе не С++, а javascript

Comment: поймали за руку

Comment: @Neuro, да, протупил